# jQuery Active Tab with HTML attribute

Tags: jquery, html, tabs

Is there a way to select the jQuery active tab with a HTML propertys.

Something like:

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1" selected="true">
        tab 1
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">
        tab 2
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-3">
        tab 3
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: divs don't have a selected attribute, you should probably use class="active"

Comment: I know that divs don't have that attribute, but I want to use a attribute to select the active tab. When doing the tab active check the attribute to set the default tab.

Comment: You can use class like `selected` and then just check if element has this class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

```
alert( $('#tabs[selected="true"]').html() )
```

You can do something like this too

```
$("#tabs").tabs();
$('#tabs').tabs('select', $('div[selected=true]').attr('id'));
```

Comment: And how set this tab the active tab?

Comment: You are doing the opositte that I need. According with the attribute, how can I select the tab? On the $("#tabs").tabs(); choose the active tab according with the attribute.

Comment: Ok, so you have set the attribute selected="true" and you want to know witch one has that attribute ?

Comment: Yes! Only one will have tthis attribute, and I will select the active according with the attribute!

Comment: This is not the point. My problem is, given a element that I know how to select on code (as your second example), how set this element as a active tab on jQuery UI Tabs.

Comment: I thought you wanted to know witch element has selected="true" ... use example 2.First example set the selected="true" to the one who's been selected.

Answer (score 0):

Are you possibly looking for something like this?

```
$(function () {
    $("#tabs").tabs();
    $("#tabs").bind("tabsshow", function (event, ui) {
        window.location = ui.tab;
    });
});
```